# Send object to Java EE-server by Json

Tags: java, ios, json, jax-rs

I'm trying to send a simple object from an IOS-client to a JAX-RS-resource by Json. The json at the client-side look like this:

```
{"longitude": -122.136034834497, "latitude": 37.3666157838699}
```

And the JAX-RS-method looks like this:

```
@Path("/save")
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public MyObject saveQuizWalk(MyObject obj)
        throws JSONException {

    return myBean.saveObject(obj);
}
```

The java class looks like this:

```
public class MyObject {

private double longitude, latitude;

-----get/set------
```

If i convert an object at the server side to json, the json-string is formatted like this:

```
{"longitude":11.11,"latitude":12.11}
```

The request from the client looks like this:

```
        // Convert object to json
    let json = JSONSerializer.toJson(myObject.createJsonFriendlyObject()                   )
    print(json)
    // create the request & response
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "someurl")!)
    var response: NSURLResponse?


    // create some JSON data and configure the request

    request.HTTPBody = json.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    do {
        // send the request
        try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
    }
    catch {

    }
```

The response from the server is 400. Why is that?

Hank

Comment: Does the server provide any info in the logs? What does your full HTTP request look like? Also - does this question really have anything to do with iOS or Swift? Does it work from other clients and is broken from the iOS client?

Comment: you could get a better answer from your backend developers...

Comment: @dcsohl No, this is the only client. What can be wrong?

Comment: If you answer my first two questions instead of ignoring them and just answering the last one, I'd have a better shot at telling you what could be wrong...

Comment: Of course. No info in the logs. I've provided additional information in my question.